# How are rails migrations handled when merging feature branches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

In rails 3, how does the `db:migrate` task determine which migrations to run?

Consider the following use case:

- developer A creates a migration at timestamp t1 in his own feature branch
- developer B creates a migration at timestamp t2 in his own feature branch
- developer B merges his branch, `db:migrate` is run on the server
- developer A merges his branch

Since t1 is earlier, does developer A's migration get run or not?

I noticed the `schema_migrations` table, and I'm wondering if any migration that has not run yet will be run.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your hunch is correct - any migration not in `schema_migrations` will be run, and they will be run in timestamp order ascending.

In this case, the next time `db:migrate` is run after A merges, migration t1 will be run.